# Options for removing listings from unreponsive business directories

Tags: seo, google-search, directory-listing

I have recently upgraded to a new domain/website. It is already ranking quite well on Google.

I had listed my previous website on about 15 local business directories which I want removed. I have successfully requested to have most listings removed - but there are 3 sites that I can't edit my listing, and the only way to contact them is through a form on there site... And multiple attempts to contact them over the last month have resulted in no response or action.

I'm sure these companies are legally required to remove my personal contact details on request.  Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an attorney to write letters making the request addressed to their legal department. Give them 10 business days to respond or remove the listing. If that does not work, the attorney can file for a cease and desist order which carries penalties if ignored. If the listing still does not disappear, you can file a suit. It should be settled quickly and immediately without going to court.

None of this should cost much.

If an attorney wants to charge the same fee for writing the letter 3 times, find another attorney. They should only charge you once for the letter and an additional fee to modify it using a paralegal. This will not hold true for the cease and desist filings. As well, most attorneys use a software package that has pre-written forms, templates, and letters. Ask about this in advance. If the attorney is using one of these packages, they cannot charge you to write the letter. Some will charge you 3 times for a letter that is pre-written. If you find a lawyer like this- run. Find another one fast.

Again. None of this should cost much. Maybe just a few hundred dollars.

Comment: Thanks. My dad is a solicitor so I will ask him about writing a letter.  The problem is that these sites don't offer an address, phone number or contact email. Only an embedded contact form... I even checked Whois on the domain.  The owners contacts are not public so I tried contacting the domains 'abuse' email listed... But it bounced back.

Comment: @PaulO'Shea You can still get the address from the registrar or privacy service. You will have to write yet another letter. Lucky you that your Dad is a solicitor. I grew up with cops, lawyers, and judges in the family. The only one left is the cop- retired. I have investigated what it would take for an old guy living in the mountains to get a law degree just for this reason. I just might.

Comment: Thanks #closetnoc I was able to get a direct email of the domain owner from Whois on one of the sites and they have already responded.  I have contacted the privacy services on the others.

Comment: @PaulO'Shea Most domain owners are decent people. But sometimes there has to be a bit of a nudge or serious noise to get peoples attention.

Comment: @closetnic Agreed.

Comment: Obviously my email to the domains abuse email has been forwarded to the website owner as that listing has also been removed this morning.  2 down ... one to go.

Comment: @PaulO'Shea I think they read this thread!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

seems you do not read Google updates. In penguin update Google listed so many website as Spammy website. And links from unresponsive website can harm any website. So Google says go and remove those links before you hit by PENGUIN update.

Google suggest two options

```
1. eMail those website to remove your link
2. Disavow those links.
```

Disavow will stop Google to pass PR juice from those unresponsive websites.

Google Disavow
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main?pli=1

Comment: Yes. I am now aware that linking your site through these business directories can often do more harm to your Google rating than good. My new site is ranking just fine without being listed on any of these sorts of sites.  I simply want to remove these old listings that link to my old website so they stop showing up in Google. I've read about disavow... So may consider this option if I am unable to contact the site owners and have all listings removed.

Comment: See, everyone wants to remove bad links point to their website (So website not gain pagerank from these website. ) , But website owners are not able to fix them. So Google provide another way to stop passing pagerank.